Monitoring SQL rights deltas
so first time question. I am looking for how people generally monitor rights across SQL servers. Currently, we have a huge process that scans all servers and then it is queried into excel and pivot tables etc, huge mess. I was thinking that someone out there has a more simplified means of handling this.
I am editing this to share what I am trying and see if there is a way around the syntax issues. I am working out a trigger that each server will have to log all modifications etc, and "chatgpt suggested the same, however standard SQL logs this for creating and deleting a user, but modifying rights is not easy, I am getting Syntax errors:

USE Database
GO
CREATE TRIGGER ddlTrigger_Audit
ON DATABASE
FOR GRANT, DENY, REVOKE, CREATE_USER, ALTER_USER, DROP_USER
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @EventType NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @EventDetails NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @EventUser NVARCHAR(100);

-- Get event details
SELECT 
    @EventType = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    @EventDetails = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    @EventUser = SYSTEM_USER;

-- Log the event
INSERT INTO AuditLog (EventType, EventDetails, EventUser)
VALUES (@EventType, @EventDetails, @EventUser);

END;

The syntax is at the Grant, and I am assuming that if I solve that it will then be at Deny and Revoke. My initial thought was it was a reserved word, but bracketing that does not resolve the issue.
So, my thought was a database, which we already have on each server, then a trigger that logs anything that occurs with principal_name etc, and then just gather each server's changes into a central database that can be updated and queried whenever for reporting.
I am totally open for better ideas.
Thank you
